# COUNTIF values in ROW with ArrayFormula -google form entry calculation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-forms, countif

I am trying to count TEXT fields in my table filled by Formular. As I want to use this with document studio, copy if statement is not an option.

**Working IF statement:**

```
=((if(ISBLANK(B1:B991),"",if(row(B1:B991)=1,**"IF"**,COUNTIF(D2:BE2,"OK")))))
```

I need to put this to the arrayformula, adding data with form will delete all data in ROW(if statement is gone)

When I put this IF to arrayformula, it will calculate only values for first field.**I need it to calculate values in each row.**

**Not working arrayformula:**

```
=ArrayFormula(((if(ISBLANK(B1:B991),"",if(row(B1:B991)=1,**"ARRAZFORMULA"**,COUNTIF(D2:BE2,"OK"))))))
```

Link to the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_MipTVaI66KDrQq8w818AAb_tNvs8Ivm-TAucrYLDEs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
={"AF"; ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(N(INDIRECT("G2:"&COUNTA(B:B))="OK"), 
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(INDIRECT("G2:"&COUNTA(B:B)))^0)))}
```

[image: 0]